# JQuery JQDock Label Always Visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have looked around and cannot seem to find an answer to this trivial problem. I have created a fisheye menu using JQDock however I am unsure on how to display the label for each icon initially.

At the minute I can only dispaly and manipulate the label when the mouse is hovered over an icon and I would like to initially show the label of the icon and then maybe change the css of it when the icon is being hovered over

Thanks for any responses

Comment: Can we have some example code please. Pretty difficult to help without it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example shown on - http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/

If you use this code you will get the labels shown:

```
$("#jqDock0").find(".jqDockLabel").each(function(){
   $(this).attr('style', 'display:block');
});
```

**Update (@15:20 GMT)**:

After using your markup i have the following:

HTML:

```
<div id='page'>
    <div id='menu'>
        <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 1" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
        <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 2" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
        <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 3" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
        <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 4" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
        <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 5" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#menu").find("img").each(function(){
    $("<span>"+$(this).attr('title')+"</span>").insertAfter($(this))
});
```

Check it in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/YZ4CW/

**Update (@15:53 GMT)**:

> [jsfiddle.net/vwbfP](http://jsfiddle.net/vwbfP) (not sure if i
>   inserted it correctly but its all
>   there) – Kevin Grey 18 mins ago

I've updated your example, which is now working. http://jsfiddle.net/vwbfP/1/

Comment: thanks for your quick response. The above solution makes sense, and when checking the objects after the page has initialised the correct classes are there and ids. However for some reason my code still does not work, please see below.

Is this because the find is looking for the elements too quickly ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#menu').jqDock({
   align: 'middle',
   labels: 'bc'
  });
  
  $("#jqDock0").find(".jqDockLabel").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('style', 'display:block');
    //alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
  
 });

</script>

Comment: <div id='page'>
  <div id='menu'>
    <a href="#" title="Link 1" ><img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' /></a>
    <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 2" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
    <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 3" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
    <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 4" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
    <img src='SubMenu_item_1_a.png' title="Link 5" alt='SubMenu_item_1_b.png' />
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Your code is marked up differently to that of jqDock, therefore my solution wont work. I'll tweek it to match you markup

Comment: thank you again for your quick response, however after literally copying and pasting the above code I am receiving the error:

d.elem[..] is not an object or null? 

and im not sure how to debug it

Comment: Try pasting you code into [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and ill take a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vwbfP/ 

(not sure if i inserted it correctly but its all there)

Comment: here's your code working in jsfiddle - [http://jsfiddle.net/vwbfP/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/vwbfP/1/). I'll add this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/index.php?dt=0&pg=examples#permanent_labels (images within links, requires v1.7+) or http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/index.php?dt=0&pg=examples#permanent_labels2 (images only, requires v1.8) ?